# ORD 47min Connecting flight

Tags: short-connections, ord

is 47 min enough time between arrival and departure from OHare on United? I'm guessing I won't have to switch terminals. Arrival = 813 am , departure 900 am on another flight; I'm thinking there is no way I make the second flight...

Edit : O'Hare

Comment: Are these domestic or international flights? What is the itinerary?

Comment: Domestic. CAE - ORD - LNK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your itinerary is:

- [ASQ4301](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ASQ4301) CAE-ORD
- [ASQ4328](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ASQ4328) ORD-LNK

Looking at these flights on FlightAware, we can see that 4301 often arrives early, though occasionally it's late, and once in the last 10 days it was several hours late.

Flight 4328 appears to have departed on time exactly *once* in the last 10 days.

This suggests that your layover at ORD is likely to be longer than the scheduled 47 minutes.

4301 deplanes to Terminal 2 at the F gates, and 4328 departs from the same terminal and series of gates, so you have a very short walk to get from one plane to the next. You're very likely to make this connection, unless your plane from CAE is *significantly* late. In that case it's on United to rebook you on another flight from ORD (at no cost to you). United has two other daily ORD-LNK flights, departing at 12:25 pm and 3:50 pm.

Comment: You probably want to add that it's the airline responsibility **if** the traveller booked both flights on a single itinerary rather than independently.